# CRUD Operations and also performing Edge Cases using Selenium

Tags: java, database, selenium

I have to perform CRUD operation on a database of computers and which covers edge cases too using Selenium Framework (any).

Please help out.

Comment: Seriously though,  this is not clear at all,  please be more specific

Comment: please add some code. what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the database changes using the script then you can write a JDBC connection code which will execute those query for you on runtime.

Refer below link:-

https://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-connect-to-the-database-in-java

Now you can write a Selenium script which may execute previously on JDBC and test them on your application and once your script successfully execute database script and rerun the Selenium script to check the changes on application.